# How to handle extremely large CoreData store in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview

Say you have a core data entity with more than 10,000,000 objects in a sqlite backed core data  store, how do you effectively display all that information in an NSTableView? In particular, how do you efficiently sort, filter and display in infinite scroll mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use NSArrayController. See the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: NSArrayController is being used. But the whole experience still feels really laggy, especially when it comes to sorting and selecting.

Comment: @Tony: A sort operation has to examine every value in an unordered list (and you don't control the ordering of the underlying data store). You'll never get around that. As for the other stuff, are you doing your CoreData ops on a background thread and delivering results asynchronously? If you want the UI to remain responsive during operations that take a long time, you're going to want to move long running operations to the background, and provide some feedback to the user about long running operations. It's a complex topic, but if you're talking about UI stalls, look there.

Comment: I noticed that CoreData entity properties have an "indexed" option. Does setting it help in any way? If so, how do I know that I'm using the index to sort in coreData?